# Getting a WPF Frame to use Windows Security

Tags: wpf, frame, windows-security

I'm trying to put a frame in my program and have it access a website that is requiring window's security:

I'd be okay with entering the password when that window of my program loads, but it simply throws a the error:

System.Net.WebException was unhandled
Message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Best case scenario would be my programing being able to automatically provide the password and me being let directly into the site.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure about this but I don't think Frame can pass through credentials.  You would have to get much more complex if you want to do something like this.  For example, [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.authenticationlevel.aspx) can pass credentials through with the request.

Comment: HttpWebRequest, I'll have to look into this. If anyone is familiar with this and wants to post an answer, it would be nice to have it documented. If I get it figured out, I certainly will.